# <input type="number" /> `event.target.validity.valid` returns false for float numbers (ReactJS)

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, input, dom-events

Currently I am working on an editable table view after user uploads an excel, so they could see and edit fields that fail our validations. There is a column for weight and volume which can be a float number. (For those I am using `<input />` with `type="number`) So far, I have been using `event.target.validity.valid` from an `onBlur` function to validate number fields. On blur, if valid we update the table view, if not valid we keep the original value. However, I noticed that when blurring out with float number, `event.target.validity.valid` returns false. My question is, is there a different validation value I could use that would take into account float numbers, not just integer numbers?

I have tried using the regex, but I hate the fact that cursor jumps to the end of the input field if user types non number characters, also I do not want to alter user's input `onChange` but only `onBlur`

Thanks in advance